# Flutter overlay is moving

Tags: flutter, overlay

I'm asking how to disable Overlays to move when a Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar is called like on my video below.
The same thing is happening when the keyboard appear. Sometime the blue floattingButton (+) don't come back to it's original position :-(

Thx in advance.

[Problem animation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qke2p.gif)

Answer (score 1):

The `FloatingActionButton` going up when the `Scaffold` is displayed is something common to all default implementations.

Give a look to the "Bootom app bar" demo in the Gallery app. Press on the search button and you will see it coming up. Or just add a `Scaffold` to the app that is built with `flutter create` command.

This happens because of the way the FAB button is placed on the screen and the effect of displaying the `Snackbar` by the `Scaffold`.

The FAB button is displayed at the bottom of the content area of the `Scaffold` content. When the content area is shrinked to include the `BottomAppBar`, the FAB goes up with it. It has nothing to do with `Overlay`.

You have two options:

1. Either you create your own versión of the FAB which is not
   controlled by the `Scaffold`.
2. Or you hack the Scaffold so the size of the `SnackBar` is not taken
   into account.

For this second option you can try the following:

- Go to the file /lib/src/material/scaffold.dart in your flutter installation and look for the line with the code `snackBarSize: snackBarSize,` inside the `_ScaffoldLayout` class.
- Replace it with `snackBarSize: Size(0.0, 0.0),`

You will see that the FAB stays in its place.

Comment: Thk you for your answer chemanolins. The point is that i'm okey that a floatting button is moving but mine don't come back to it's original position.